# Accessing Azure Function App Protected By MS Entra Id From Another Client App using Client Credentials Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, clientcredential, microsoft-entra-id

I am very new to working with Azure Entra Id.

I have an Azure Function app containing Http triggered functions. I need to protect the function app by Entra Id and access it from client app in non interactive mode (client credentials flow)

I have created an App registration in Entra Id and using it to enable the Function App Authentication. I have exposed an API from the registered app.
I got all the details like ClientId, Client Secret, Object Id, Scopes, Auth endpoint, Token endpoint.

With all these I am easily able to get the access token using postman with Client Credentials Flow and access the Functions.

Now my doubt is, I have created only one app registration and in the Function app Authenticate, hooked that App registration. I have not created any separate App registration for the client app.
But everywhere including MS documentation, I see we need to create two different App registration for client credentials flow, one for the function app and another for the client app.
I am not understanding what is the reason to create two different app registration? What is the point I am missing out here?

Comment: Yes you can also use one Azure Ad app to access the functions. Two separate app registrations is suggested to ensure that each app has its own set permissions. This helps to prevent unauthorized access to your resources and to ensure that each app can only access the resources that it is authorized to access.

Comment: More secure access is granted in creating two applications. There is no harm in creating one application and accessing the function.

Comment: @Rukmini , So If I understand correctly, the need of app registration for the client app comes only when I want to protect the client app from user. If I want to keep the client app open may be, then in that case no need to create an app registration for the client app.                                                                                          Only for the azure function app I can create an app registration. I can get the client id, secrets and other details and use it in the client app to get access token.

Comment: Yes you are right. If you are okay with the solution can I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: If you want to protect the client application, then you must create two Azure AD applications. This ensures more security and helps to prevent unauthorized access to your resources.

- You can create one client application also to access Azure Function API.
- If you want to protect the client app from the user or not to keep it open, you can create two applications based on your requirement.

I created an **Azure AD Function app** like below:

[image]

In Azure AD application added API permissions (created only one app):

[image]

Generated access token via Postman:

[image]

Using the above access token, I am able to access function api:

```json
GET https://testrukfunctapp1.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1

x-functions-key : FunctionURLCodeValue
Content-Type : application/json
```

[image]

- If you want to create two applications, the Expose the API in Client application.
- Then grant the API permission in the other application not the actual client application.